# How to remove Method name from wsdl in .netcore

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the method name from the wsdl removed. I refered to many stackoverflow queries and tried using MessageContract(IsWrapped=false) and also set the below on the ServiceContract and OperationContract

*[XmlSerializerFormat(Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, SupportFaults = true)]*

But still no luck, the method name comes in the soap request in SoapUI as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:the="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetResult> <!--need to remove this-->
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Pet>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <the:Name>?</the:Name>
         </tem:Pet>
      </tem:GetResult> <!--need to remove this-->
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


[ServiceContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat(Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, SupportFaults = true)]
interface IPetService
{

    [OperationContract]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, SupportFaults = true)]
    string GetResult(Pet test);
}

[MessageContract(IsWrapped = false)]
public class Pet
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The project in .net core 3.1 and using soapcore package.

Any advice would be highly appreciated?
Thanks.

Comment: Why? If you remove that it's not really SOAP anymore... https://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-soap12-part0-20070427/#L1165

Comment: We are trying to replicate a SOAP service for a client and this was a requirement.

Comment: Did u get it finally? i have the same problem